# How can I encode string in base64 using jstl tag?

Tags: java, base64, jstl, encode, taglib

I want to encode string in base64 using jstl tag on jsp page.

Example:

```
<a href="deleteBatch.do?batchId=12"
```

encoded

```
<a href="deleteBatch.do?batchId=12hgxb4"
```

How could I do this?

Comment: example:<a href="deleteBatch.do?batchId=12" and encode url like <a href="deleteBatch.do?batchId=12gs4m"

Comment: No, no, this question is okay, don't close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do with basic jstl. But you can easily implement your taglib, or execute the conversion from your servlet filters, and use the variables from your taglib. I will show you some example code late afternoon.